# How to create/add columns using a variable in a loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, create-table, alter

I am very new to SQL in that I just finished reading [Sams Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672336073) and that is my only SQL knowledge. So now that I'm done with the book, I'm trying to create some tables so I can play around with them. I can easily create a table with a known amount of columns and specified header. Where I am having trouble is creating a table with an unknown amount of columns and a date as the header. What I have tried so far is this:

```
DECLARE @start_date AS DATE
DECLARE @end_date AS DATE
DECLARE @curr_date AS DATE
DECLARE @column_name AS CHAR(10)

SET @start_date = 2016-01-02
SET @end_date = 2016-12-31
SET @curr_date = @start_date

WHILE @curr_date < @end_date
    SET @curr_date = DATEADD(DD, 7, @curr_date)
    ALTER TABLE Project_1
        ADD @curr_date  DOUBLE
```

What I tried to do here is make a start and end point for the loop and use the loop condition which is stored in a local variable as my column header since that is what I need the column to be titled. I also tried using `CAST` to cast it as a char but the DBMS is delighted to let me know that there is `Incorrect syntax near '@curr_date'` on that last line (the ADD line) because it doesn't like that I'm trying to name a column with a local variable (I think). I don't have a sample output but the output should be a table with the first column defined as CHAR and titled `emp_name` because it will be holding names. All other columns defined as type `DOUBLE` and should be `NULL` because they will be holding a number of hours and must have the current date as the header `@curr_date`. I think all columns added to a table through the `ALTER` method are defaulted to `NULL` anyways. I've seen examples of dynamic SQL where you declare a variable to hold the select statement but I don't really understand how they add columns to a table. I'm not sure if this can be done in the `CREATE` statement but if it can that would be great to see. Also, this needs to be variable in the fact that I could change the `@end_date` to lets say... they year 2046.

Security is not an issue here

Comment: This is usually not something you would ever do as the users of a schema generally prefer fixed table definitions (not dynamic ones with a variable number of columns based on a date range). However you can construct a sql string (`declare @sql varchar(2000)`), populate it with an alter statement, and then run it using `EXEC` or `sp_executesql`

Comment: What do you mean by "header"? Is that the column name? You do NOT want to use dates as column names. Not only is that painful to work with it is a sign of a very poor design. Also, consider how many columns it would be to have a column for every day between today and 2046. You would exceed the maximum number of columns by several orders of magnitude.

Comment: please give us a use case so we can show you how to make a better design.

Comment: @Sean Lange Yes, by column header I mean column name. I wouldn't actually need it to go from now to 2046 but I would have it go from the beginning of one year to the end of that same year. Plus I only need 52 columns for each table. I don't really know the limitations of SQL Server as I'm still very new but thank you for the comment, it got me thinking.

Comment: You don't want dates as column names. That indicates there are some serious normalization problems. Since you stated 52 I am guessing you want data for each week of a year? Normally you would have each week be a row in the table, not another column.

Comment: Exactly, I want data for each week of the year and I'm seeing now how I can make a better table doing it your way. Again this is my first ever table and I have not read a book about database design. But thank you for taking your time to comment as it is was really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with all of the comments about using ROWs not dynamically adding columns you can always dynamically pivot those latter and it will have more flexibily.  So maybe some schema considerations but just to answer your specific question you where close.....

```
DECLARE @start_date AS DATE
DECLARE @end_date AS DATE
DECLARE @curr_date AS DATE
DECLARE @column_name AS CHAR(10)

SET @start_date = '2016-01-02'
SET @end_date = '2016-12-31'
SET @curr_date = @start_date

WHILE @curr_date < @end_date
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @curr_date = DATEADD(DD, 7, @curr_date)

    SET @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE TableB
        ADD [' + CAST(@curr_date AS VARCHAR(10)) + ']  FLOAT'

    --PRINT @SQL
    EXECUTE (@SQL)
END
```