# SQL Server: how does quoting work in creating columns inside for-loop dynamically?

Tags: sql-server, for-loop, sql-server-2014, quotes, declare

I think I am getting a quoting problem. I want to replace

```
  ,CAST(REPLACE([NET_VALUE_1M],',','.') as float)/SUM(CAST(REPLACE([NET_VALUE_1M],',','.') as float)) OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [CMONTH] ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as 'NET_VALUE_1M_PROP_2Mp'
  ,CAST(REPLACE([NET_VALUE_1M],',','.') as float)/SUM(CAST(REPLACE([NET_VALUE_1M],',','.') as float)) OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [CMONTH] ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as 'NET_VALUE_1M_PROP_3Mp'
  ,CAST(REPLACE([NET_VALUE_1M],',','.') as float)/SUM(CAST(REPLACE([NET_VALUE_1M],',','.') as float)) OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [CMONTH] ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as 'NET_VALUE_1M_PROP_4Mp'
  ,CAST(REPLACE([NET_VALUE_1M],',','.') as float)/SUM(CAST(REPLACE([NET_VALUE_1M],',','.') as float)) OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [CMONTH] ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as 'NET_VALUE_1M_PROP_5Mp'
  ,CAST(REPLACE([NET_VALUE_1M],',','.') as float)/SUM(CAST(REPLACE([NET_VALUE_1M],',','.') as float)) OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [CMONTH] ROWS BETWEEN 5 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as 'NET_VALUE_1M_PROP_6Mp'
  ,CAST(REPLACE([NET_VALUE_1M],',','.') as float)/SUM(CAST(REPLACE([NET_VALUE_1M],',','.') as float)) OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [CMONTH] ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as 'NET_VALUE_1M_PROP_7Mp'
  ,CAST(REPLACE([NET_VALUE_1M],',','.') as float)/SUM(CAST(REPLACE([NET_VALUE_1M],',','.') as float)) OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [CMONTH] ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as 'NET_VALUE_1M_PROP_8Mp'
  ,CAST(REPLACE([NET_VALUE_1M],',','.') as float)/SUM(CAST(REPLACE([NET_VALUE_1M],',','.') as float)) OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [CMONTH] ROWS BETWEEN 8 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as 'NET_VALUE_1M_PROP_9Mp'
  ,CAST(REPLACE([NET_VALUE_1M],',','.') as float)/SUM(CAST(REPLACE([NET_VALUE_1M],',','.') as float)) OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [CMONTH] ROWS BETWEEN 9 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as 'NET_VALUE_1M_PROP_10Mp'
  ,CAST(REPLACE([NET_VALUE_1M],',','.') as float)/SUM(CAST(REPLACE([NET_VALUE_1M],',','.') as float)) OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [CMONTH] ROWS BETWEEN 10 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as 'NET_VALUE_1M_PROP_11Mp'
  ,CAST(REPLACE([NET_VALUE_1M],',','.') as float)/SUM(CAST(REPLACE([NET_VALUE_1M],',','.') as float)) OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [CMONTH] ROWS BETWEEN 11 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as 'NET_VALUE_1M_PROP_12Mp'
  ,CAST(REPLACE([NET_VALUE_1M],',','.') as float)/SUM(CAST(REPLACE([NET_VALUE_1M],',','.') as float)) OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [CMONTH] ROWS BETWEEN 12 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as 'NET_VALUE_1M_PROP_13Mp'
```

with a while loop

```
SELECT

      CAST(REPLACE([NET_VALUE_1M],',','.') as float)
      /
     SUM(CAST(REPLACE([NET_VALUE_1M],',','.') as float)) 
         OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [CMONTH] 
            ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as 'NET_VALUE_1M_PROP_2Mp'


      DECLARE @cnt INT =2;
      DECLARE @cnt_total INT =12;

      WHILE @cnt < @cnt_total 
      BEGIN
        DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
        SET @SQL =',CAST(REPLACE([NET_VALUE_1M],',','.') as float)
             /
          SUM(CAST(REPLACE([NET_VALUE_1M],',','.') as float)) 
                 OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [CMONTH] ROWS 
                   BETWEEN @cnt PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
                       as ['NET_VALUE_1M_PROP_']+@cnt+['Mp']'
      EXECUTE(@SQL)

        SET @cnt=@cnt+1;
      END;


  FROM [Channel_AGG]
```

causing an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

How does the quoting work to declare the SQL command? I tried `['` opening quote and `']` for closing quote, as shown here  [How to create/add columns using a variable in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38233002/how-to-create-add-columns-using-a-variable-in-a-loop), but errors continuing. So to create the initial command inside a for-loop in SQL Server 2014?

Comment: how about you declare @SQL first?

Comment: @Jeremy correct,  `DELARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)`, but the quoting issue persist.

Comment: well, it is not included in your code... are we psychic? :)

Comment: Sorry but [dynamic SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/dynamic-sql) does not work like that.  You have to build the entire SQL statement, inside a string var, and then execute it.  Can you explain why you want to move away from your first approach?  Do the number of output columns continually change?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you're trying to do, or what you expect to happen when trying to execute that incomplete fragment of code, but your quoting problem can be solved by using two single quotes for each single quote inside a string. e.g.:

```
 ',CAST(REPLACE([NET_VALUE_1M],'','',''.'') as float)
             /
          SUM(CAST(REPLACE([NET_VALUE_1M],'','',''.'') as float)) 
                 OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [CMONTH] ROWS 
                   BETWEEN '+convert(nvarchar(10),@cnt-1)+' PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
                       as [NET_VALUE_1M_PROP_'+convert(nvarchar(10),@cnt)+'Mp]'
```

You will also need to convert `@cnt` to a character type before concatenating.

You should declare your `@sql` outside of your loop, and probably be concatenating (e.g. `@sql =+ ...` or `@sql = @sql + ...`) instead of resetting the value inside the loop.

Instead of blinding trying to `exec(@sql)`, you might want to see what you are creating with `print @sql` or `select @sql` instead.